# Web comic comparing Star Wars with Foundation

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, foundation, webcomics

A while ago I saw a cartoon depicting one person describing a famous un-filmed scifi story to someone else. The story sounded like Star Wars but was revealed to be Asimov's 'Foundation Trilogy'.

My Google-fu has failed me and I can't find it. Can anyone else dig out a link for me?

Comment: Where do you usually read your web-comics? What was the style used (Western, colour, anime, etc)? Was it a static comic or a cartoon animations?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Try to provide as much information as possible. It helps our community better help you! I hope you get the answer you seek and stick around.

Comment: was it a comic or an infographic?

Comment: Not a comic, but the wikipedia page on "Star Wars sources and analogues" specifically mentions Isaac Asimov stating a "close resemblance" between Star Wars and Foundation.  Might assist someone's searches.

Comment: Your question intrigue me, I hope if you find it, you will post answer.